# npm global list keeps changing

Tags: node.js, npm, command-prompt

Very new `npm` and `node.js`. I'm having a weird problem, whenever I type

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

it always shows the packages that I am currently in, most cases it shows up as empty. Correct me if I am wrong but I thought your global path is supposed to be fixed, it's the place where you can install all the packages that works on your command prompt correct?
Also when I type `node -v` it works fine but it doesn't show up as a global package.
I've been stuck on this for a few days, hope someone is able to help.
for example this is what I'm getting.

```
F:\node.js>node -v
v8.9.0

F:\node.js>npm list -g --depth=0
F:\node.js
+--  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'F:\node.js\node_modules\etc\package.json
`-- npm@5.5.1

npm ERR! error in F:\node.js\node_modules\etc: ENOENT: no such file or 
directory, open 'F:\node.js\nod
e_modules\etc\package.json'

F:\node.js>cd programs

F:\node.js\programs>npm list -g --depth=0
F:\node.js\programs
`-- (empty)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the behaviour you're seeing? Like output from the commands in different setups? Do you have any global packages installed for them to show up there?

Comment: Yes of course, I have node installed on my backup hard drive, but when I type in npm list -g --depth=0 on F:\ >it shows up as empty however whenever I put the same code on F:\node.js> it shows an error: ENOENT there is no such file or directory opened at 'F:\node.js\node_modules\etc\package.json' and it also shows my global npm package and it's latest verson 5.5.1 but that's it.

Comment: @horia Coman
F:\node.js>node -v
v8.9.0

F:\node.js>npm list -g --depth=0
F:\node.js
+--  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\node.js\node_modules\etc\package.json
`-- npm@5.5.1

npm ERR! error in F:\node.js\node_modules\etc: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\node.js\nod
e_modules\etc\package.json'

F:\node.js>cd programs

F:\node.js\programs>npm list -g --depth=0
F:\node.js\programs
`-- (empty)

I apologize didn't even think of using my code editor to copy and paste

Comment: could you put the message as part of the original question && with proper formatting. I think the ENOENT error code might be a big clue.

Comment: Yah sorry, this is actually my first post on stack over flow.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for anyone that needs to know

```
npm config set prefix=
```

then set where you want it to go.